# Is there an easy method i can use R's areaplot() with steps instead of interpolated points?

Tags: r, plot, area

Is there an easy method i can use R's `areaplot()` with steps instead of interpolated points?
Like `type = "S"` in normal plot function.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any way to use `areaplot()`, but you can probably get what you want with `rect()`. You should provide reproducible data using `dput()` to get an answer that takes the characteristics of your specific data into account.

```
# Some data
x <- 1:10
y <- c(39L, 42L, 33L, 38L, 45L, 53L, 28L, 33L, 39L, 42L)

plot(NA, xlim=c(0, tail(x, 1)), ylim=c(0, max(y)), xlab="X", ylab="Y")
rect(c(0, x), rep(0, 11), c(x, tail(x, 1)), c(y, tail(y, 1)), col="gray", border=NA)
```

We need to draw a rectangle for each value. Since we have 10 values, we draw 10 rectangles. The `rect()` function uses the lower left and upper right corners to define each rectangle.

[image]